# Server Alias With wildcard subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, debian-lenny, virtualhost, serveralias

I am using WordPress network subdomain setup. I had to put  `*.mydomain.com` as a server alias but now I also have a site `subdomain.mydomain.com` that leads to another directory. Is there a way of doing this since when I type `subdomain.mydomain.com` it just loads the WordPress sign up page.

I do have a virtualhost setup for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have two VirtualHosts:

1. VH for WP that hosts *.mydomain.com
2. VH for independant webiste that hosts subdomain.mydomain.com

Make sure that your `subdomain.mydomain.com` VirtualHost is loaded or located in file *before* the VirtualHost with ServerAlias of `*.mydomain.com`.

Apache will use the 1st VH it finds that matches ServerName/Alias.

Then restart Apache.

Edit:

In file it should be...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

You can get the default VH and load order by running:
    httpd -S

Comment: I did this and the subdomain.mydomain.com loads no matter what. Can you show me an example of the vhost config i need

Comment: xLRDxREVENGEx, edited.

Comment: Do I use documentroot or directory

Comment: xLRDxREVENGEx, I'm not sure what you mean? Each VH block should have a DocumentRoot, and a Directory block giving access and override permissions (and options) for that DocumentRoot.

Comment: Ok well i had this setup before and any time i viewed any site that had mydomain.com it always went to the same page

Comment: xLRDxREVENGEx, it sounds like both of your VHs had the same exact DocumentRoot. That or, you mean that all your *.mydomain.com subs wne to the same DocumentRoot, which they would since it's the same VH ... unless you use VirtualDocumentRoot instead.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. Nothing is in the apache logs.